# How to read from line x to line y using StreamReader

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a text file containing a lot of short stories spread over multiple lines. I want to get one story at a time and convert it to a string.

**Example:**

```
//Story A
Aaaa AAA aaaaa AAA
Aaa A A aaaa AA aaa
A Aaaa AAA aaaaa A A

//Story B
BBB b BBb BB bbb BB
BBB bb bb bb BB BB
BB bbb BBBB bbbb
```

**How can I get all lines of Story A and convert it to a string without having to load Story B?** (There are going to be many other stories so loading them all isn't an option as it will occupy a lot of RAM)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I haven't really written anything but I've been looking online for a solution. I haven't been programming for too long so I'm not too familiar with StreamReader or File.ReadAllLines so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: It would seem that you have added a _delimiter_ in the form of a line that contains only `//Story X`. You haven't explicitly said so, but it that your strategy for determining what the boundary between stories is?

Comment: @Wyck Yes, those help me find the stories if I'm editing them but could also be used to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static [File Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8) in the [System.IO Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.8) has a lot of handy methods to process files. The [File.ReadLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8) will save memory:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> ReadLines (string path);
```

The point is that it reads the file line by line, keeping only the current line in memory (plus the current file buffer, but not the whole file).

Using some LINQ, you can get the right story with

```
string storyTitle = "//Story A";
var story = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    File.ReadLines(theFile)
    .SkipWhile(s => s != storyTitle)
    .Skip(1) // Skip the current title
    .TakeWhile(s => !s.StartsWith("//")) // Next story title
);
```

We must skip the current story title with `.Skip(1)`, otherwise `.TakeWhile` immediately stops reading lines.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it solves my problem. But would this still be fast if there are 3000+ lines?

Comment: It is as fast as it can. Reading files is always bit slow compared to in-memory operations. If you want to speed this up, you would have to store each story in its own record in a database table and put an index on the story title. But you won't get a better performance with < 1000 stories, as index seeks start to have an advantage over table scans only if the number of records is big enough.